# SWF not showing up when server is running

Tags: html, flash, flex4.6, flash-builder4.5

I have a very simple HTML page which loads a swf using swfobject. If I just have all three files in the same folder then when I double-click the HTML page in the Finder(mac) or Windows Explorer (windows) everything works fine.

However, when I run Tomcat or put it on a server, the page is blank. I can see the divs saying "hello" and "goodbye" that should be above and below, respectively, the swf. And the space is correctly left for the swf itself; if I change height from 300 to 200 then 'goodbye' is that much less far down from 'hello'. What is more, if I right-click that space, it shows me the Flash context Menu -- Zoom In, Show All, Play, Loop, About Adobe Flash Player, etc. In other words the swf appears to be there, but it's blank -- white like the rest of the page.

Here's the HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Dynamic embed</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div>Hello</div>
<div id="myContent">
    <p>Alternative content</p>
</div>
<div>Goodbye</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    swfobject.embedSWF("snapshot.swf", "myContent", "300",     "300",     "9.0.0");
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT: added the missing HTML, as pointed out in comments. The page I tested did indeed have these elements included.

Comment: I don't see 'hello' or 'goodbye' in your code, are you sure it is not in your Flash file?

Comment: Also, the closing tags `</body></html>` are missing